# Access SharePoint hosted add-in remotely

Tags: sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app, sharepoint-on-prem

I have a SharePoint environment on a virtual machine. I can access all my SharePoint webs from my physical computer. But when it comes to SharePoint add-ins I get an error : "This page can't be displayed". I do not get that error when I access add-ins from within my virtual machine.
I'm pretty new in that area so let me know if you need more details.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researches, I've found the solution : I had to edit the "host" file of my physical computer to map the app domain URL with my VM IP.